# How to reach vault deployed on a dedicated cluster from another cluster within same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I'm quite lost and I need some clear guidance.

I have created 2 kubernetes clusters on aws in a VPC. Each cluster has their own subnets.

The first cluster "MI" is dedicated to micro services and applications needing vault secrets

The second one "VA" is dedicated to consul/vault.

Obviously the idea is to make the "MI" cluster talks to vault in the "VA" cluster. In the init container of each micro service I would get a vault token like that:

```
$(curl -sS --request POST $VAULT_ADDRESS/v1/auth/kubernetes/login -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"role":"$VAULT_POLICY","jwt":"$JWT"}' --insecure | jq -r 'if .errors then . else .auth.client_token end')
```

To achieve that, even though it's not recommended, I need a load balancer as my cluster nodes are not reachable, they only have private ip... right ?

On this matter, the documentation says:

> Sometimes clients use load balancers as an initial method to access
>   one of the Vault servers, but actually have direct access to each
>   Vault node. In this case, the Vault servers should actually be set up
>   as described in the above section, since for redirection purposes the
>   clients have direct access.

In my case bearing in mind, vault nodes are behind VPC, I guess that paragraph does not apply to me as I would not be able to reach those address directly.

Then it says:

> However, if the only access to the Vault servers is via the load
>   balancer, the api_addr on each node should be the same: the address of
>   the load balancer. Clients that reach a standby node will be
>   redirected back to the load balancer; at that point hopefully the load
>   balancer's configuration will have been updated to know the address of
>   the current leader. This can cause a redirect loop and as such is not
>   a recommended setup when it can be avoided.

I guess I'm in that situation since my vault instances will only be available through the ELB right?
To make this work I understand I have to set

```
api_addr = "https://$(LOAD_BALANCER_ADDR):8200"
```

is there any way to fix the redirect loop ?

I've seen that configuration using ELB also set up global ip for it.
I don't understand why static ip matters ? Isn't DNS sufficient ?

On AWS you cannot create global ip for LB, but since kubernetes 1.9 you can use network LB which has static IP?

So would you advise classic LB or latest NLB ?

Comment: That's a lot of questions without stating what you have _already tried_; I personally use ELBs in TCP mode for vault, and the vault instances know their [`api_addr`](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/#api_addr) and `cluster_addr` as the DNS name that is CNAME-ed to their ELB; the standby vault instances respond to [`/v1/sys/health`](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/system/health.html#429) with HTTP 429 when in standby mode, meaning you can add them to the ELB and they will not receive traffic until they are active

Comment: How many vault servers you have in your K8S cluster VA? If you have just one cluster, so ELB won't be a problem.